# compiling a folder tree as a source folder with g++

Tags: c++, directory, compilation, g++, mingw

I'm trying to compile a proyect that has a src folder that inside has ramification folders for different contexts or types of code 
An example of this could be:

```
src
├ model
│ └ -cpp files-
├ view
│ └ -cpp files-
└ controller
  └ -cpp files-
```

Just an example, I would have a bunch of folders for different things, all needed for the program to work

But I don't know how to tell g++ to compile any folder format inside src 
I know about sayinig `g++ -o out src/*.cpp` (for cpp files in just src/) 
or `g++ -o out src/*` (that does the same thing [src only has .cpp files])
but when I try the last one I get: 
`... :cannot find src/clase: Permission denied`
being "clase" a folder that is accessed by main.cpp by running:
`#include "clase/miclase.cpp"`
that particular try was using the folder structure:

```
src
├ main.cpp
└ clase
  └ miclase.cpp
```

I would need a recursive file inclusion to the compilation, and I have no clue about that or alteratives, help please